# WPF Passing multiple parameters to viewmodel (Easily)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using the MVVM pattern, and I find WPF overly complex to use. Every minor task takes many lines of code. I have encountered a very simple issue, which I need to solve. But every instruction I find (converters, multibinding...) seems way too complex for such an extremely simple task. Here's an illustration:

[image: My application]

When button "Svar" is clicked, "Object a" (type `object`) and Object b (type `string`) should be sent to the ViewModel. I have already implemented the `ICommand` and passing the list item works, but it seems like just passing one more bit of information suddenly demands tens of lines of code in addition. How would you guys approach this task?

Update: 
Some code. ViewModel:

```
class ViewModelMain : ViewModelBase
{
    public object _selectedItem { get; set; }
    ICommand _answer;

    public void AnalyzeAnswer(MemEntity memEntity)
    {
        if(ReviewService.IsCorrectAnswer("", memEntity))
        Console.Beep(1000, 200);
    }

    public ICommand Answer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_answer == null)
            {
                _answer = new RelayCommand(
                    p => true,
                    p => this.AnalyzeAnswer((MemEntity)p));
            }
            return _answer;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MemEntity> items { get; set; }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.Beep(1000, 200);
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public ViewModelMain()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<MemEntity> {
        new MemEntity { Word1 = "a", Correct = 3, Incorrect = 1 },
        new MemEntity { Word1 = "b", Correct = 1, Incorrect = 0 },
        new MemEntity { Word1 = "c", Correct = 30, Incorrect = 5 }
    };
}
```

View:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="items" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="266" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" ItemsSource="{Binding items}" DisplayMemberPath="Word1"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Word1}"/>
    <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="189,212,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Value="{Binding SelectedItem.Proficiency, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="#FF0672B0"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="189,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.025,0.478"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" Content="Svar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="331,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78"/>
    <Label Content="Statistikk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138"/>
    <Label Content="3 korrekt og 2 feil" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108"/>
    <ToolBarTray HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
        <ToolBar VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,-79,0">
            <Button Content="Lagre" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Button Content="Åpne" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
    <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="0,306,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If you need to "send to the viewmodel" you're likely not doing it the mvvm way. Everything on that form should be bound to viewmodel properties and your Command should just act on those properties' values. If you need to notify other parts of your app, send a Message with a Model. To get a specific answer, you'd need to show some code.

Comment: The word I should have used is bind. I'm using commands, and trying my best to use MVVM. When saying "sending" I meant in the form of CommandParameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If your `SelectedItem` is a `MemEntity`, declare it as `MemEntity`, not as `object`;

2) Bind the `TextBox.Text` property to a string property in your ViewModel;

3) Bind the command to a simple `Action` without parameter, calling inside it the `object` and the `string`;

4) Use the C#-6.0 `nameof` feature to raise the property change notification.

Something like this:

```
public class ViewModelMain : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelMain()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<MemEntity> {
            new MemEntity { Word1 = "a", Correct = 3, Incorrect = 1 },
            new MemEntity { Word1 = "b", Correct = 1, Incorrect = 0 },
            new MemEntity { Word1 = "c", Correct = 30, Incorrect = 5 }
        };
    }

    public ICommand Answer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_answer == null)
            {
                _answer = new RelayCommand(
                    p => true,
                    p => AnalyzeAnswer());
            }
            return _answer;
        }
    }
    private ICommand _answer;

    public void AnalyzeAnswer()
    {
        //use SelectedItem and Text in this method,
        //you don't need to pass them as parameters
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MemEntity> Items { get; set; }

    public MemEntity SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.Beep(1000, 200);
            _SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
    }
    private MemEntity _SelectedItem;
}
```

And in xaml, leaving layout properties apart (margins, sizes, etc), the `Button` would be:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethingCommand}"
        Content="Svar"/>
```

And the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
```

There is no easiest and shortest way.
MVVM can seem verbose, but it's the minimum required to:

1. decouple the UI from the logic;
2. loosely bind these two together;
3. give you all the functionalities you need.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you for the code example and such an elaborate answer. Yes, WPF can be a bit overwhelming at first, but I'm slowly getting the hang of it.